# How can I generate a new row out of two other rows in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some data in a Postgres table that looks like this:

```
1 apple datetime1
2 orange datetime2
3 apple datetime3
4 orange datetime4
5 apple datetime5
6 orange datetime6
.
```

The datetime is always in ascending order and the majority of times the apple rows are inserted first and orange second with some exceptions that I have to catch and eliminate.

What I practically need is a Postgres query that will pair apples and oranges only:

```
1 apple datetime1 2 orange datetime2
3 apple datetime3 4 orange datetime4
5 apple datetime5 6 orange datetime6
```

Apples should never be paired with other apples and oranges should never be paired with other oranges.

There are couple of conditions:

1) In the newly generated rows apple should always be first and orange second.

2) Always pair apple and orange rows with the closest datetimes and ignore the other rows.

For example if I have the original data looking like this:

```
1 apple datetime1
2 apple datetime2
3 orange datetime3
4 orange datetime4
```

pair

```
2 apple datetime2 3 orange datetime3
```

and ignore rows

```
1 apple datetime1
4 orange datetime4
```

Any ideas how to do this in Postgres?

Comment: Exactly two fuits - `apple` / `orange`? No other and no NULL?

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter There are some other fruits in the same table but for this report I just have to find and pair apples with oranges.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Ok, This time you do the CTE, alright?

Comment: @wildplasser: You got it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10884184/939860

Comment: +1 btw, for making yourself very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with CTE & window function:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT *
          ,lead(tbl) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS y
    FROM tbl
    )
SELECT x.id,     x.fruit,   x.dt
     , (y).id, (y).fruit, (y).dt
FROM   x
WHERE  fruit = 'apple'
AND    (y).fruit = 'orange'
ORDER  BY x.id;
```

Could be done as subquery just as well, but per [request from @wildplasser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883651/how-can-i-generate-a-new-row-out-of-two-other-rows-in-postgres#comment14185141_10883651). :)

I pick the whole "next" row per window function [`lead()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html). Note the syntax with parenthesis to access columns of the composite (row) type `y`.

Comment: I understood the OP wanted the match on closest timestamp, not on closest ID? But it is very compact, indeed.

Comment: @wildplasser: The same in this case because of: `The datetime is always in ascending order`.

Answer (score 2):

> The datetime is always in ascending order and the majority of times the apple rows are inserted first and orange second with some exceptions that I have to catch and eliminate.

If I understand correctly, you want to find if there are any two consecutive rows with the same fruit, right?

If so, you can do it like this:

```
WITH Q AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datetime) R
    FROM YOUR_TABLE
)
SELECT *
FROM Q Q1 JOIN Q Q2 ON Q1.R = Q2.R - 1
WHERE Q1.fruit = Q2.fruit;
```

In plain English: join every row with the next one (where the meaning of "next" is determined by the `datetime` ordering) and check if their fruits match. You can play with it in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/1a8a8/20).

*BTW, this is not a good database design. You should consider a redesign so "invalid" situation you described above is naturally prevented by the database structure itself.*

Comment: The OP made it very clear that he wants `apple` followed by `orange` and *not* `two consecutive rows with the same fruit`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter For apple to be followed by orange it cannot be followed by apple. He wants two consecutive fruits detected, so he can "eliminate" them. I'm not clear whether he wants them eliminated by deleting from the table or just by omitting them from the query result - my answer should help in the former case.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    t0.id, t0.fruit, t0.datetime, 
    t1.id, t1.fruit, t1.datetime
from t t0
inner join t t1 on 
    t0.fruit = 'apple' 
    and 
    t1.fruit = 'orange'
    and
    t0.datetime < t1.datetime
order by t1.datetime - t0.datetime
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET search_path='lutser';

DROP TABLE fruits;
CREATE TABLE fruits
    ( id INTEGER NOT NULL
    , fruit varchar
    , zdate varchar
    );  
INSERT INTO fruits(id,fruit,zdate)
VALUES

(1, 'apple', 'datetime01')
, (2, 'orange', 'datetime02')
, (3, 'apple', 'datetime03')
, (4, 'orange', 'datetime04')
, (5, 'apple', 'datetime05')
, (6, 'orange', 'datetime06')
, (11, 'apple', 'datetime11')
, (12, 'apple', 'datetime12')
, (13, 'orange', 'datetime13')
, (14, 'orange', 'datetime14')
    ;

SELECT fa.id, fa.fruit, fa.zdate
    , fo.id, fo.fruit, fo.zdate
FROM fruits fa
JOIN fruits fo ON fa.zdate < fo.zdate
WHERE fa.fruit = 'apple' AND fo.fruit = 'orange'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM fruits nx
    WHERE nx.fruit = 'orange'
    AND nx.zdate > fa.zdate
    AND nx.zdate < fo.zdate
    )   
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM fruits nx
    WHERE nx.fruit = 'apple'
    AND nx.zdate < fo.zdate
    AND nx.zdate > fa.zdate
    )   
    ;
```

Result:

```
DROP TABLE
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 10
 id | fruit |   zdate    | id | fruit  |   zdate    
----+-------+------------+----+--------+------------
  1 | apple | datetime01 |  2 | orange | datetime02
  3 | apple | datetime03 |  4 | orange | datetime04
  5 | apple | datetime05 |  6 | orange | datetime06
 12 | apple | datetime12 | 13 | orange | datetime13
(4 rows)
```